# Toolbar Title Uppercase

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-styles

Trying to uppercase the title of a toolbar:

**Toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/App.Theme.ToolbarTitleUppercase"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/App.Theme.ToolbarTitleUppercase" />
```

**Toolbar style**

```
<style name="App.Theme.ToolbarTitleUppercase" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

This is not having any effect on the title text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This is with support library 27.1.1 set app:theme

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTextAppearance"
 />
```

Then in ToolbarTextAppearance in styles.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarTextAppearance">
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This works for me. But I would perform the steps the other way round as it make the IDE hang looking for the `ToolbarTextAppearance` style before it's been defined.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071790/1617737), here's another way to do it:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <!--<item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>-->
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a toolbar.xml on layout folder:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_layout">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_title"
                android:text="Title text"
                android:textAllCaps="true" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Include it on the xml you want to use the toolbar:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

And then inside your view:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'd like to style the default title. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use Material Toolbar like this:

put app:titleCentered="true" to make your text in the center

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/main_color"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleCentered="true"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />
```